Can anyone identify this please?
If anyone can tell me what this is part of I would appreciate the help


I think you forgot to add an image...

Turns out that @AFOL_UK did add the image, but somehow managed to delete part of the markup for it. Fortunately the URL was in there still.

For when this gets reopened: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75266-1

@IvanSanchez I've reopened this. Feel free to share an answer.

This is set 75266-1 "Sith Troopers Battle Pack":

(Found it by paging through Star Wars microfigthers and just stumbling into battle packs)
